# Obtaining a subset of the correlation matrix of a dataframe having only features that are less correlated

Tags: pandas

If I have a correlation matrix of features for a given target, like this:

```
      feat1      feat2     feat3     feat4     feat5

feat1   1                      ....

feat2             1

feat3                        1

feat4                                 1

feat5      ....                                  1
```

how can I end up with a *subset* of the original correlation matrix give only some features that are less correlated? Let's say

```
      feat2     feat3     feat5

feat2   1                 ....
    
feat3             1
    
feat5      ....             1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to subset you just need to `loc` on both axis, i.e.:

```
In [105]: df                                                                                   
Out[105]: 
     0    1    2     3    4
0  0.4  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.00  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.45  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  1.0

target = [0, 2, 3]  # ['featX', 'featY', 'etc']
subset = df.loc[target, target]
```

Or if you want to filter by some logic, do it in steps:

```
corr = pd.Series(np.diag(df), index=df.index)
high_corr = corr[corr > 0.7].index
subset = df.loc[high_corr, high_corr]

In [114]: subset                                                                               
Out[114]: 
     1    2    4
1  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0
```